# Tensorflow Python: How to apply a dense layer consecutively across a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an input tensor shaped [?, 6, 2] and a window size of 3. I want to slide the window along my inputs, concatenate them, and run them through a dense layer that takes 6 inputs and has 1 output.

It would run concatenated input values at indexes [0-2], [1-3], [2-4], [3-5] and the dense network outputs would be concatenated to create a new tensor of size 4.

So [?, 6, 2] -> [?, 4]

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I feel like this can maybe be done with conv2d, but not really sure how to formulate it.

Comment: You question is not very clear. maybe try tf.reshape ?

Comment: So I can reshape it from [?, 6, 2] to [?, 12] and then apply the dense layer consecutively by skipping 2 indexes, how would I do that?

Comment: Would you give an example?